# Communication between VDCs on Cisco Nexus 7000 via virtual interface

Tags: cisco, cisco-nx-os, cisco-nexus, virtual

Is there any way to create a virtual interface of sorts between two VDCs on a single Nexus 7000 switch?  I've read that a physical cable is required (which is lame) however I wasn't sure if this was a feature that was added in a newer NX-OS release.  I'm currently running NX-OS v6.2(14).

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? You should accept an answer if it in any way helped you out, so that others can get help too.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do what you want to do. VDCs virtualize control plane and data plane in protected memory so that each is an independent virtual device, just like independent physical devices. You can, of course, ask Cisco to consider adding this feature in a future NX-OS release.

From [Cisco Nexus 7000 Series NX-OS Virtual Device Context Configuration Guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/nx-os/virtual_device_context/configuration/guide/b-7k-Cisco-Nexus-7000-Series-NX-OS-Virtual-Device-Context-Configuration-Guide.pdf):

> **Communication Between VDCs**
>
> The Cisco NX-OS software does not support direct communication between
>   VDCs on a single physical device.
>   You must make a physical connection from a port allocated to one VDC
>   to a port allocated to the other VDC to allow the VDCs to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Physical cable is required. It's security function.

As Ron Maupin said, you can ask TAC to submit a feature request but I think you're going to have a hard time making a business case for it.